# cross table in R shows meaningless values

Tags: r, dataframe, tapply

I have the following dataframe in R:

```
|   zurs_bk_hq gdv_gk anz |
|-------------------------|
| 1        223      2   6 |
| 2         96      3  23 |
| 3        223      4   2 |
```

With `with(df, tapply(anz, list(zurs_bk_hq, gdv_gk), FUN=sum))`

```
                   2                   3                 4       
 ------------------- ------------------- ------------------ 
  96             NA        1.136351e-322                NA                  
  223 2.964394e-323                   NA     9.881313e-324
```

I get a meaningless result.

However, with `df$anz <- 1` the result is

```
        2   3   4  
 ----------------- 
   96  NA   1  NA             
  223   1  NA   1
```

Frankly, I have no clue...

Many thanks in advance, Karsten

Comment: Could you provide a MWE where we can see exactly the data that you use. You dont show how you read in that table

Comment: what is the meaningful output for your goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not get your result:

```
df <- structure(list(zurs_bk_hq = c(223L, 96L, 223L), gdv_gk = 2:4, 
    anz = c(6L, 23L, 2L)), class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
with(df, tapply(anz, list(zurs_bk_hq, gdv_gk), FUN=sum))
#      2  3  4
# 96  NA 23 NA
# 223  6 NA  2
```

Alternatively you can use `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(anz~zurs_bk_hq+gdv_gk, df, sum)
#   zurs_bk_hq gdv_gk anz
# 1        223      2   6
# 2         96      3  23
# 3        223      4   2
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answers.  I got the table as a result via dbFetch from a postgresql.  The meaningful output is the one shown after the with-statement in the answer provided by @dcarlson.  The problem was that the colunm `anz` was produced as int64. After formatting with `df$anz <- as.numeric(df$anz)` I got the result I wanted.  Many thanks again for your prompt response, stay healthy